# How to bind $scope.$on to two actions, but only execute one function?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Problem:

I have a directive which is used in two places, but do the same exact thing (hence 1 directive).

The problem is that one of the two objects created by the directive needs to respond to multiple broadcast messages (as opposed to a single message) either of two messages that are broadcasted (that are created in the link function).

### To reiterate:

- object 1 (if !$scope.ismini)

  - needs to respond to the message "video-switch"
- object 2 (if $scope.ismini)

  - needs to respond to the message "video-switch"
  - also needs to respond to the message "calendar-state-changed"
  - needs to only execute the action only once (regardless of which is called).

```js
       return {
            restrict: "A",
            scope: {
                ismini: "="
            },
            link($scope, element: JQuery, attrs, ctrl) {
                $scope.$on("video-switch",() => {
                    setWordCloud(element, $scope.ismini);
                });

                if ($scope.ismini) {
                    $scope.$on("calendar-state-changed",() => {
                        setWordCloud(element, $scope.ismini);
                    });
                }

            }
        }
```

What would be the best approach to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Create a function with the logic and use it in both location, opposed to creating 2 anonymous with the same logic and debounce that function when called.
Meaning put a timer on the function, reset the timer if another function tried to run the same function before the timeout occurs.

```
return {
    link($scope, element: JQuery, attrs, ctrl) {
        var processChange = function()
            setWordCloud(element, $scope.ismini);
        };
        var timeoutId;
        $scope.$on("video-switch", function() {
            $timeout.cancel(timeoutId);
            timeoutId = $timeout(processChange, 10, true);
        });

        if ($scope.ismini) {
            $scope.$on("calendar-state-changed", function() {
            $timeout.cancel(timeoutId);
            timeoutId = $timeout(processChange, 10, true);
        })

    }
}
```

A disadvantage to this would be that another $digest loop will occur which could cause screen flickering but there really is no other option if both functions could be called and you only want to run them once.

Comment: But the problem still exists where if $scope.isMini, it will be called twice. Once for "video-switch" and once for "calendar-state-changed"